# How do I get SublimeLinter to stop reporting false-positive errors?

Tags: rvm, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

The problem is that SublimeLinter will sometimes report lines as containing errors, when they actually don't. One example of this is a line like `format.html { redirect_to :action => :index }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because SublimeLinter is using the system ruby, instead of the ruby for your gemset. See, the Ruby linter that SublimeLinter uses is extremely simple. It just runs the code through `ruby -wc` and marks any output in the code. But that's the problem. Sublime Text 2 isn't using the `ruby` that your Rails app uses.

You can change the SublimeLinter settings to correct this issue by opening the `Sublime Text 2` menu, going into Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter, and selecting `Settings - User`. Add this text to the file, save it, and restart Sublime Text 2:

```
{
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "ruby": "rvm-auto-ruby"
    }
}
```